# NoSuchMethodError Exception with SetLocale

Tags: java, android, xamarin, locale, setlocale

In Xamarin, I have created the following extension to change locale on the fly:

```
public static void ToEnglishLocale(this Activity activity)
{
    Locale locale = new Locale("en-US");
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.SetLocale(locale);
    activity.BaseContext.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(config, activity.BaseContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
}
```

I am targeting API 15 an up and it fails with the following exception on API 15:

```
Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='setLocale' signature='(Ljava/util/Locale;)V' in class Landroid/content/res/Configuration;
```

Is there any other "unified" way to change locale on the fly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The method SetLocale](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#setLocale%28java.util.Locale%29) was added in api level 17 so that's why you are getting the error.

You can use `Android.OS.Build.Version.SdkInt` property to find api version at runtime and call the method only if it is `Android.OS.Build.VERSION_CODES.JellyBeanMr1` or newer. If it isn't you should set the [Locale public property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Content.Res.Configuration.Locale/) instead of calling `SetLocale`